# Compute distance between strings of two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have 2 data frames:

```
df1:
Date       Name   Num  
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 

df2:
Date       Name   Num  
2013-11-24 Celery 22.1 
2013-11-24 0r@nge  8.6 
2013-11-24 @ppl3   7.6 
2013-11-24 BananaX 10.2
```

I want to find similar rows, for that, I need to find similarity of `Name` between 2 data frame right now I am iterating each data frame and compute similarity with all the other rows of the other data frame (which is very time consuming) and find the maximum value and if it was greater than certain threshold I will do something with it.

```
dfResult = pd.DataFrame()
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
for indexD, rowD in dfD.iterrows():
    for indexS, rowS in dfS.iterrows():
        data = pd.DataFrame({"ratio": fuzz.token_set_ratio(rowD['Name'], rowS['Name']),
                             "indexD": rowD['Num'], "indexS": rowS['Num']}, index=[indexS])
    maxMatch = dfTMP.loc[dfTMP['ratio'].idxmax()]
    ......
    ......
    ......
    resultMatch = create_match_row(maxMatch, dfD, dfS)
```

After each iteration I am getting

```
indexD      1
indexS      4
ratio     100
Name: 3, dtype: int64
1
indexD     2
indexS     1
ratio     35
Name: 0, dtype: int64
2
indexD     3
indexS     3
ratio     45
Name: 2, dtype: int64
3
indexD     4
indexS     4
ratio     33
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

which the max function should return :

```
    indexD      1
    indexS      4
    ratio     100
```

Which means row 1 from data frame 1 is similar to row 4 in data frame 2.

I wanted to know is there any better way so I can compute the distance in one shot and remove the inner loop? and find the best match for each row (`name`) in the first data frame with the second data frame?

Expected output: for each row in data frame one I like to get the data frame (just a simple index) that shows which row in data frame 2 is the most identical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUIC, Here's one way

```
In [3456]: def get_fuzz(df, w):
      ...:     s = df['Name'].apply(lambda y: fuzz.token_set_ratio(y, w))
      ...:     idx = s.idxmax()
      ...:     return {'name': df['Name'].iloc[idx], 'index': idx, 'val': s.max()}
      ...:

In [3457]: df1['Name'].apply(lambda x: get_fuzz(df2, x))
Out[3457]:
0    {u'index': 3, u'name': u'BananaX', u'val': 92}
1     {u'index': 1, u'name': u'0r@nge', u'val': 67}
2      {u'index': 2, u'name': u'@ppl3', u'val': 67}
3    {u'index': 0, u'name': u'Celery', u'val': 100}
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

`assign` the result to `df1`, if you need

```
In [3458]: df1.assign(search=df1['Name'].apply(lambda x: get_fuzz(df2, x)))
Out[3458]:
         Date    Name   Num                                          search
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1  {u'index': 3, u'name': u'BananaX', u'val': 92}
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6   {u'index': 1, u'name': u'0r@nge', u'val': 67}
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6    {u'index': 2, u'name': u'@ppl3', u'val': 67}
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2  {u'index': 0, u'name': u'Celery', u'val': 100}
```

---

Details

```
In [3459]: df1
Out[3459]:
         Date    Name   Num
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2

In [3460]: df2
Out[3460]:
         Date     Name   Num
0  2013-11-24   Celery  22.1
1  2013-11-24   0r@nge   8.6
2  2013-11-24    @ppl3   7.6
3  2013-11-24  BananaX  10.2
```

Comment: I cant interpret your output, can you explain a little bit? for each row in df1, it shows the row index in df2 with maximum distance similarity in `name`?

Comment: Yes, for each row of `df1`, you get a dictionary,  for values which has highest fuzzy match in `df2` index, name, and ratio value. Which is pretty much you need, instead of separate dataframes, you've it in single dataframe.

Comment: it sounds good, upvoted, gonna accept it after I finish my code